# PostgreSQL: SQLstate: 22003 numeric overflow

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL (mixbest) with 73018 rows. The fields that I want to select are:

```
sample integer
m      integer,
pciv   double precision,
aggrec double precision 
soil   character(1)
```

I'm trying a SELECT but I get the following error SQLstate: 22003 numeric overflow. My select:

```
SELECT sample, m, 1-(EXP(SUM(LN(1-pciv)))) pciv, avg (aggrec) aggrec_avg, soil 
FROM mixbest  
GROUP BY sample,  m,  soil;
```

I know the problem is the EXP() due to I've tried the same select with the expression (SUM(LN(1-pciv)))) and I don't get the same error.

I tried to execute the select only in a few lines, and it works:

```
SELECT sample, m, 1-(EXP(SUM(LN(1-pciv)))) pciv, avg (aggrec) aggrec_avg, soil 
FROM mixbest 
WHERE  sample< 4492 GROUP BY sample,  m,  soil;
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you show what `select max(pciv) from (SELECT sample, m, SUM(LN(1-pciv)) pciv, avg (aggrec) aggrec_avg, soil 
FROM mixbest  
GROUP BY sample,  m,  soil) t;` gives?

Comment: Sure, the result of  `select max(pciv) from (SELECT sample, m, SUM(LN(1-pciv)) pciv, avg (aggrec) aggrec_avg, soil FROM mixbest GROUP BY sample, m, soil) t;`  is -16.1561356371564

Comment: Ok, negative numbers, now could you show the result of `select min(pciv) from (SELECT sample, m, SUM(LN(1-pciv)) pciv, avg (aggrec) aggrec_avg, soil FROM mixbest GROUP BY sample, m, soil) t;` ?

Comment: Ok `-8075.01457220042`, maybe it is too small?

Comment: Definitely, it's too small. I mean, Postgresql have to solve 1/(e^8075). e^8075 is extremely large value.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I thought...

Is it possible to controll this error? With something similar to `Coalesce (1-(EXP(SUM(LN(1-pciv)))), 0)` but controlling the error, not the not null...I've been looking for this but I haven't seen any similar.

Comment: I think no. Because of an exception raising. You can create a stored procedure. Well... I'll post it in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I guess:

```
create or replace function mixbest_avg(out sample int, out m int, out pciv double precision, out aggrec_avg double precision, out soil character(1))
    returns setof record as
$$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        SELECT t.sample _sample, t.m _m, SUM(LN(1-t.pciv)) _pciv, avg(t.aggrec) _aggrec, t.soil _soil
            FROM mixbest t
            GROUP BY t.sample, t.m, t.soil
    loop
        begin
            rec._pciv = 1 - exp(rec._pciv);
        exception
            when numeric_value_out_of_range then -- here we catch an exception
                rec._pciv = 0; -- or other default value
        end;

        select rec._sample, rec._m, rec._pciv, rec._aggrec, rec._soil into sample, m, pciv, aggrec_avg, soil;
        return next;
    end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```